# ajax Customer register how to continue the process?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, controllers, redirect

In my custom controller I am checking if customer is logged in or not.If not redirects to customer login page .

```
public function customaddAction()
{


    if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
        $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');

    }
    if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
    {           
     $sampleid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('sampleid');

      $collection=Mage::getSingleton('mymodule/mymodule')->customisesaved($sampleid);
    if($collection)
    {
    $this->_redirect('mymodule/mymodule/customshow');
    }
    else{
             $this->_redirectReferer();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my custom controller from where I am checking if customer is logged in or not.
But **if the customer is new when he registers using ajax registration it redirect to MyAccount page but I want to continue my controller action.**
Suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the customer is new or not than you need to create custom customer attribute named "is_new".
Use this extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes-1.html

Create observer for customer_save_after and customer_register_success.

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>doSomething</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
        <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>doSomething</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
    </events>
</global>
```

Create Oberver.php

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    protected $canDoSomething = false;

    public function doSomething($observer)
    {
        if (!$this->canDoSomething) {

            //here your code
            //set is_new = 1 here

            //now set flag to true to prevent executing your code twice 
            $this->canDoSomething = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Overrides the _loginPostRedirect method of default AccountController to redirect on custom URL.

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class MagentoPycho_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{

   /**
     * Overriding defaults redirect URL 
     * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
     */
    protected function _loginPostRedirect()
    {    
        $session    = $this->_getSession();        
        // $is_new = get customer data and check for is_new attribute value.

        if($is_new == 1){
            // redirect to your custom module
            // set is_new attribute value to 0.
        }else{
            if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl() ) {

                // Set default URL to redirect customer to
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());

                // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
                if ($session->isLoggedIn())
                {
                    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard')) {
                        if ($referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)) {
                            $referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
                            if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
                }
            }
        }

        $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));        
    }
}
```

Now this code will check if the customer is new than it will redirect to your module else default behaviour

Comment: you can also use observer to achieve this.

Ref. http://blog.belvg.com/magento-tips-how-to-redirect-a-user-to-other-page-than-his-account-page-after-login-in-magento.html

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't want to always redirect to my custom controller ** only when my custom controller action is called the new registered customer should continue my controller action.**

Comment: you can add that logical part in if condition `if(1 == $custom_login_redirect_flag){`

Comment: check `created_at` date to find new registered customer.

Comment: please check my updated question. with my custom controller action.

Comment: Updated answer. please check and let me if it works for you or not

Comment: thanks for answer how to get my sample id in the observer function.I am passing sample id as parameter to my controller.

Comment: i tried to get   `$sampleid=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('sampleid'); `                  but since it is executing registeration I am not getting the sample id. can u please tell any way to get mycustom contoller  parameters in observer

Answer (score 0):

Please Look at below configuration That will help you to solve your problem

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer i had made this changes but still it does not execute my controller action when user is creating new account

Comment: try to enable Enable Guest Checkout And test its working or not

Comment: I want to execute my controller for register  customer only